# Managing many TikZ-pictures in text

Tags: floats, wrap

I need tools to arrange tikz pictures in my document. I want put picture  near the it text like in this picture [image]

```
 \documentclass[12 pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[russian]{babel}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{a4paper, margin= 1.5cm, bmargin= 2cm }

 %Image-related packages
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{wrapfig}
 \usepackage{circuitikz}





 \title{Problems}
 \author{ILDAR}
 \date{February 2017}

 \begin{document}
 \tikzset{component/.style={draw,thick,circle,fill=white,minimum size           =0.75cm,inner sep=0pt}}
 \tikzset{component1/.style={draw,thick,dashed,circle,fill=white,minimum size =0.75cm,inner sep=0pt}}





 \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0.9,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (0.9,2);
 \draw (2.1,2) -- (3,2)-- (3.9,2);
  \draw (0.9,1.8) rectangle node {\large R} (2.1,2.2);
 \draw (3.9,1.8) rectangle node {\large 2R} (5.1,2.2);
 \draw (3,2) -- (3,1.4);
 \draw (3,0.6) -- (3,0);
 \draw (3,1)circle(0.4cm)  node {\large A};

 \draw (0.9,-0.2) rectangle node {\large R} (2.1,0.2);
 \draw (3.9,-0.2) rectangle node {\large 3R} (5.1,0.2);

 \draw (2.1,0) -- (3,0)-- (3.2,0) -- node[above] {\large K} (3.6,0.2);
         \draw (3.7,0) -- (3.9,0);
 \draw (5.1,2) -- (6,2) -- (6,0) -- (5.1,0);

 \draw (0,0) -- (0,-0.5) -- (2.7,-0.5);
 \draw (6,0) -- (6,-0.5) -- (3.3,-0.5);
 \draw (2.75,-0.5)circle(0.05cm);
 \draw (3.25,-0.5)circle(0.05cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}


 Схема, изображённая на рис. 9.2, состоит из четырёх резисторов, идеального амперметра и 
 ключа К. Сопротивления всех резисторов указаны на рисунке. Если ключ замкнут, амперметр 
  показывает значение Ii = 0,5 А. Какое значение силы тока I2 будет   показывать амперметр, если 
  ключ разомкнуть? Напряжение в цепи в обоих случаях одинаковое.


  \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0.4,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (0.4,2);
 \draw (1.6,2) -- (2,2)-- (2.4,2);
 \draw (0.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large R} (1.6,2.2);
 \draw (2.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large 2R} (3.6,2.2);
 \draw (2,2) -- (2,1.4);
 \draw (2,0.6) -- (2,0);
 \draw (2,1)circle(0.4cm)  node {\large A};

 \draw (0.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large 3R} (1.6,0.2);
 \draw (2.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large R} (3.6,0.2);

 \draw (1.6,0) -- (2,0) -- (2.4,0);
 \draw (3.6,2) -- (4,2) -- (4,0) -- (3.6,0);


 \draw (0,1) -- (-0.3,1);
  \draw (-0.35,1)circle(0.05cm);

  \draw (4,1) -- (4.4,1);
  \draw (4.4,0.8) rectangle node {\large 5R} (5.6,1.2);
  \draw (5.6,1) -- (6,1);
  \draw (6.05,1)circle(0.05cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}


 Определите показания амперметра, если через резистор 5R течёт ток 48 А.   Ответ дать в амперах. Амперметр считать идеальным.


 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0.4,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (0.4,2);
 \draw (1.6,2) -- (2,2)-- (2.4,2);
 \draw (0.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large R} (1.6,2.2);
 \draw (2.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large 2R} (3.6,2.2);
 \draw (2,2) -- (2,1.4);
 \draw (2,0.6) -- (2,0);
 \draw (2,1)circle(0.4cm)  node {\large V};

 \draw (0.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large 3R} (1.6,0.2);
 \draw (2.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large R} (3.6,0.2);

 \draw (1.6,0) -- (2,0) -- (2.4,0);
 \draw (3.6,2) -- (4,2) -- (4,0) -- (3.6,0);


 \draw (0,1) -- (-0.3,1);
  \draw (-0.35,1)circle(0.05cm);

  \draw (4,1) -- (4.4,1);
  \draw (4.4,0.8) rectangle node {\large R} (5.6,1.2);
  \draw (5.6,1) -- (6,1);
  \draw (6.05,1)circle(0.05cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}


 Определите, к какому внешнему напряжению подключена схема, если вольтметр           показывает
 U = 5 В. Ответ дать в вольтах, округлить до целых. Сопротивление вольтметра гораздо больше сопротивлений резисторов.

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Place them into two column tabular?

Answer (score 2):

This illustrates how to do it using both minipages and wrapfig, illustrating the problems with both.

With minipage, you first store the image in savebox 0, the width of which is now available as `\wd0` and the height as `\ht0`.  One can then compute the width of the minipage using `\dimexpr`.  While it is possible to set the baseline for a tikzpicture, one can use `\raisebox` on anything.  The distance from the top of the text to the baseline is given by `\topskip` or `\ht\strutbox`.

Note that minipages reset `\parindent` to 0pt.

Wrapfig actually does the same thing internally, except is uses `\parshape` to set the right margin.  It also assumes every line is spaced `\baselineskip` apart and continues past the end of the figure.  The undocumented command `\WFclear` tells wrapfig to stop formatting text, and you need to skip past the bottom of the figure before starting another.

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[russian]{babel}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
 \usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{a4paper, margin= 1.5cm, bmargin= 2cm }

 %Image-related packages
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{wrapfig}
 \usepackage{circuitikz}

 \title{Problems}
 \author{ILDAR}
 \date{February 2017}

 \begin{document}
 \tikzset{component/.style={draw,thick,circle,fill=white,minimum size           =0.75cm,inner sep=0pt}}
 \tikzset{component1/.style={draw,thick,dashed,circle,fill=white,minimum size =0.75cm,inner sep=0pt}}

 \sbox0{\begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (0.9,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (0.9,2);
 \draw (2.1,2) -- (3,2)-- (3.9,2);
  \draw (0.9,1.8) rectangle node {\large R} (2.1,2.2);
 \draw (3.9,1.8) rectangle node {\large 2R} (5.1,2.2);
 \draw (3,2) -- (3,1.4);
 \draw (3,0.6) -- (3,0);
 \draw (3,1)circle(0.4cm)  node {\large A};

 \draw (0.9,-0.2) rectangle node {\large R} (2.1,0.2);
 \draw (3.9,-0.2) rectangle node {\large 3R} (5.1,0.2);

 \draw (2.1,0) -- (3,0)-- (3.2,0) -- node[above] {\large K} (3.6,0.2);
         \draw (3.7,0) -- (3.9,0);
 \draw (5.1,2) -- (6,2) -- (6,0) -- (5.1,0);

 \draw (0,0) -- (0,-0.5) -- (2.7,-0.5);
 \draw (6,0) -- (6,-0.5) -- (3.3,-0.5);
 \draw (2.75,-0.5)circle(0.05cm);
 \draw (3.25,-0.5)circle(0.05cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}}%
\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd0-\columnsep}
 Схема, изображённая на рис. 9.2, состоит из четырёх резисторов, идеального амперметра и 
 ключа К. Сопротивления всех резисторов указаны на рисунке. Если ключ замкнут, амперметр 
  показывает значение Ii = 0,5 А. Какое значение силы тока I2 будет   показывать амперметр, если 
  ключ разомкнуть? Напряжение в цепи в обоих случаях одинаковое.
\end{minipage}\hfill
\raisebox{\dimexpr\topskip-\ht0}{\usebox0}
\bigskip

\intextsep=0pt %Note: this will also affect the spacing for figures
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}% it will compute the width automatically
  \begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0.4,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (0.4,2);
 \draw (1.6,2) -- (2,2)-- (2.4,2);
 \draw (0.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large R} (1.6,2.2);
 \draw (2.4,1.8) rectangle node {\large 2R} (3.6,2.2);
 \draw (2,2) -- (2,1.4);
 \draw (2,0.6) -- (2,0);
 \draw (2,1)circle(0.4cm)  node {\large A};

 \draw (0.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large 3R} (1.6,0.2);
 \draw (2.4,-0.2) rectangle node {\large R} (3.6,0.2);

 \draw (1.6,0) -- (2,0) -- (2.4,0);
 \draw (3.6,2) -- (4,2) -- (4,0) -- (3.6,0);


 \draw (0,1) -- (-0.3,1);
  \draw (-0.35,1)circle(0.05cm);

  \draw (4,1) -- (4.4,1);
  \draw (4.4,0.8) rectangle node {\large 5R} (5.6,1.2);
  \draw (5.6,1) -- (6,1);
  \draw (6.05,1)circle(0.05cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}
 Определите показания амперметра, если через резистор 5R течёт ток 48 А.   Ответ дать в амперах. Амперметр считать идеальным.
\WFclear
\vspace{3\baselineskip}
\hrule


    \end{document}
```